# 「私も同じ問題を抱えています」はコメントなら投稿しても良い？

Tags: 討議

[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/38861/)で回答として「私も同じ問題を抱えています」がありました。
この後、コメントに変換されているのですが、コメントでは「同じ問題を抱えています」と投稿して良いのでしょうか？

[コメントについてのヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)を読む限りでは用途にあっていないような気がします。
また個人的には「質問に対して解決したか？」「解決した場合は自己回答してください。」などは良いと思いますが、「私も同じ問題を抱えています」はよろしくないかと思います。
（どちらも質問者に解決したかを訪ねていますが、聞き方の問題な気はします。
聞き方により他のユーザが「私も同じ問題を抱えています」と賛同しかねないことに不安があります）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

変換した本人です。そこまで意識せずに変換していたので、言われてみて、コメントとして適格かどうかの基準が、どうなっているんだっけ? と思うに至りました。

#### 考えてみたこと: 自分の認識

おそらく、コメントは以下の原則があると思っています。

- Be Nice に違反する投稿は不適格
- コメントがごちゃごちゃしたり、コメントの中に回答情報が断片化されていくことで、第三者が読み辛くなる自体は避けられるべき (質問・回答・コメントのモデレーションによって整理されていくべき)

一方、「問題解決」のフレームで考えてみれば、問題に対して理解できていないことを質問して、問題を整理し、議論をすることは、これの価値は確実に存在していると思っています。

- 問題提起(問題共有) -> 議論など情報の発散・紆余曲折 -> サマリー

のステップがあるのだとすれば、その、問題空間を把握・整理するために行われるコミュニケーションのもろもろが、必要になるのだと考えます。個人的には、この発散した情報を整理・体系化するプロセスがモデレーションと我々が読んでいる行為なのではないか、と思っています。

そう考えていくと、コメントは問題を解決したくって善意で行われているのならば、それはコミュニティのルールとしては許容されるべきだと思います。一方で、コメントは今言った性質上、一過的な情報を記述するものなので、それが削除されていくのは別にその投稿が悪いとかそういうことではなく、ただよりよい情報源として整理していくプロセスの一環なのだ、と理解することが大事だと思います。

#### 翻って: 今回のケース

仮に上記のようなプロセスで問題解決が行われるのだとしたら、今回の問題は、まだ解決に至っていません。それが解決に至る途中経過として今の質問・コメントたちを見てみると、むしろ該当のコメントはないよりある方がいいのではないか、と思ったりもします。 (この、「私もこの問題に直面していますコメントが、あと何個か追加されていったとしたらそうでもないのではないですが。。そのあとに来る有益な別のコメントがうもれてしまうので)

おそらくこういった意識が自分の中にあって、コメントに変換を行ったのだと思います。ポイントは、コメント含めた投稿たちが、その問題解決の状況に応じて整理整頓されている状態になっているかどうかだと思っています。

コメントのモデレーションは、ともすれば他人の気にくわない発言を修正しにかかる、といったような使い方に陥るリスクを孕んでいるので、基本的には「通報により削除を促す」運用でしかこれが行えないようになっていますが、このように考えていくと、スタックオーバーフローで必要なモデレーションの一種であると個人的には思っています。

なので、対応が必要だと思った場合には、flag(通報) していただければ、と思います。